# scrollmagic not responding to the trigger element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic, gasp

I have problems with the ScrollMagic. It's not responding at all on the trigger   element. Below I'll provide with the code:

the CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 3000px;
}

#trigger {
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
}

.katrori {
    opacity: 0; 
    position:relative; 
    top:300px; 
    background-color:#eee; 
    height:400px; 
    padding:25px; 
    font-family:Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function($)) {
    var controller = new ScrollMagic();
    var tween = TweenMax.to(".katrori", 0.5, {opacity: 1, backgroundColor: "#1d1d1d"})
    var scene = new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#trigger"})
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You are missing **proper indentation** for one thing ;) But seriously, could you set up a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Separator/pen/xZMOJz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JS` has mainly two errors.

1. You have one `parenthesis` (")") too many.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function($)) {
                               ^^ --> one of those
   ```
2. You are using ScrollMagic version **>=2** (which you should) but use their functions from version **1**. Here is their [documentation](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html) for the **current** versions.

   The correct way to initialize the `container` and `scene` is now:

   ```
   var container = new ScrollMagic.Container({...});
   var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({...});
   ```

When you apply **these changes** a working example of your `code` might look like [**this**](http://codepen.io/IvanModric/pen/xZMOyJ):

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller(),
        tween = TweenMax.to(".katrori", 0.5, {opacity: 1, backgroundColor: "#1d1d1d"}),
        scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger"});

    scene
        .setTween(tween)
        .addTo(controller);
});
```

You might also want to look at their [examples](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/index.html).

**EDIT**

Addition to bulletpoint **2:**

In `ScrollMagic` version **1** the `container` and `scene` were initialized **in the script** this way:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic({ *global options applying to all scenes added*});
var scene = new ScrollScene({ *options for the scene* })
```

In version **2** the same thing is done this way:

```
var container = new ScrollMagic.Container({...});
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({...});
```

That's why you script didn't work before. The `styling` is still done in `CSS`.

Comment: thanx a lot man :) this helped me a lot even though i had to add duration and offset to make it work. so what about the container u mentioned above? i didnt understand it quite well. i styled the container via css. do i have to initialize it on the JS file as well ?

Comment: yah, nice. thanx for the edit as well. i didnt know that there r 2 versions of scrollmagic. i just stumbled through different examples on interent and abviously i mixed it up :P now im aware of the second version so this heleped me a lot. thanx again ;) maybe i'll have other questions while working on this...